# IBM Bluemix - Watson Alchemy - How to refer to a local directory on my laptop

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, personality-insights

Currently, I am using the following code to do analysis for a website:

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from watson_developer_cloud import AlchemyLanguageV1

alchemy_language = AlchemyLanguageV1(api_key='YOUR API KEY')

url = 'https://developer.ibm.com/watson/blog/2015/11/03/price-reduction-
for-watson-personality-insights/'

combined_operations = ['page-image', 'entity', 'keyword', 'title', 
'author', 'taxonomy', 'concept', 'doc-emotion'] 
print(json.dumps(alchemy_language.combined(url=url, 
extract=combined_operations), indent=2))
```

Can anyone tell me how to refer to a local directory where I am having my own html file for analysis? I tried to use the following code and it is not working:

```
#html ='C:\Users\Downloads\Python\name8.htm'
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `html` you need to provide a string variable that contains the HTML code you want to analyze. In your code, you are trying using a file path as the content. Obviously, that's not HTML code.

Try with:

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from watson_developer_cloud import AlchemyLanguageV1

alchemy_language = AlchemyLanguageV1(api_key='YOUR API KEY')

combined_operations = ['page-image', 'entity', 'keyword', 'title',
                       'author', 'taxonomy', 'concept', 'doc-emotion']

with open('C:\Users\Downloads\Python\name8.htm', 'rb') as html:
    print(json.dumps(alchemy_language.combined(html=html.read(),
          extract=combined_operations), indent=2))
```